# How to edit the default cakephp 3 style?

Tags: css, cakephp-3.0

I'm new to CakePHP 3, I'm familiar with CakePHP 2 but I'm totally confused as to how to edit the CSS of the default theme/layout.

There are 2 CSS files and `cake.css` and `base.css`.

`base.css` has an inline (one line) of CSS which seems to define the layout, how on earth do I edit it or work with it? am I missing some?

Comment: You can simply add _(or rewrite the existing CSS rules in the files)_ your own CSS files right? Just like you did in Cake 2 I assume?

Comment: You're not forced to use the default CSS files that come with Cake app. They are just here as example to have a default style. You can remove them in `Layout/default.ctp` and use your own.

Comment: I see that if i remove the cake.css from the default layout and add my own i can make my own styles. Thanks for your help.